# Does lambda object construction cost a lot?

Tags: c++, performance, lambda

For some purpose, one may declare a functor in a frequently callee function. Will the construction of the functor cost a lot, or just comparable to defining a plain struct?

```
void f() {
    static int x = 0;
    auto a = [&](){ x += 1;};
    for (auto i = 0, i < 10; ++i) {
        a();
    }
}

// somewhere else call f thousands of times
f()
```

**Edit** Updated the sample code.

Comment: @Zinki Nah, that question is too much about `std::function`. Not a sufficiently good fit.

Comment: Will the construction of the functor cost a lot: nope.    https://godbolt.org/g/yzKGzs  Also, you need to provide an [mcve] and a compiler and platform for any performance-related questions.

Comment: If one replaces the syntax errors in your pseudo code with compilable code, and then passes it through an optimizing compiler, [one sees no actual lambda object is created](https://godbolt.org/g/B1mvm6). So it's always good to measure/inspect assembly.

Comment: FYI: ignoring the wrong syntax for `for`, the `a()` does not construct anything it's just a call. And in this case no lambda would need to be "constructed" anyway. The compiler will just inline the definition (even if it doesn't captureless lambda is equivalent to a simple free function).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A lambda is generally cheap.

```
SomeType var;
auto lambda = [var](){ /* ... */ }
```

here, `lambda` is just an instance of an anonymous type. The type itself is processed at compile-time, so no worries. What happens at run-time though is the capture of variables (here `var`). When a capture is done by value, the value itself is copied into the lambda instance. This is what costs. When a capture is done by reference, the reference is copied into the lambda, which is cheap.

For your information, the code displayed is equivalent to:

```
SomeType var;
struct anonymous {
    anonymous(SomeType st) : st(st) {}
    void operator()() { /* .... */ }
private:
    SomeType st;
} lambda(var);
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is as always: it depends.

Depending on what the lambda looks like the compiler may be able to make it into a function pointer, or just inline it. For more complicated stuff the construction cost will be similar to a struct.

You should always measure what performance you get for your particular use case.

Comment: In what sense would it be "similar to a struct"? It is a struct (or more precisely, a class type) itself.

Comment: Yes - unless it has been optimized away. I chose not to go into the implementation details.